# I reset the current branch to the first commit and now I don't know how to go back

Tags: git

I really hope anyone can help me.

Using Git Extensions, I used the action 'Reset current branch to here' on the first commit, choosing the 'Soft' option.

Now I want to go back where I was, but I can't see how!!!

I can see that the files in my directory haven't changed (luckily).
But my whole history of commits has vanished leaving just one: The first commit.

git commit says I have staged 55 files. What do I do?

Should I type?

```
git reset HEAD@{1}
```

This is the output of **git reflog**

```
c970e12 HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to c970e12368007c5b8714143d2ae96476d818f37a
1317b0a HEAD@{1}: commit: Hide map on the bottom left
....
c970e12 HEAD@{10}: commit (initial): First commit
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: the good thing you did while doing a reset is that you didn't pass the --hard option that is why none of your files in the file system has not changed.

Comment: I learnt not to use the --hard option the hard way in the past. I lost lots of files and that made reject GIT for some time but now I'm back :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that looks good to me. For completeness, you may want to use the same `--soft` option you already used:

```
git reset --soft HEAD@{1}
```

which would be an additional guarantee that no data will be changed in your working directory or index. You say you didn't modify anything, but why take chances?

For the next time you want to take a look at an older commit, it's better to use the `checkout` command (or the GUI equivalent), which keeps `master` exactly as it was, and lets you switch back by checking out `master`.

Comment: Instead of creating a new branch I renamed it, so my intention wasn't take a look, I wanted to go back and create a master branch with the original files.

Comment: Ah, yes, in that case, if you had actually still had the reference to the commits, and if I'm understanding you correctly, then `reset` would have been the correct option.